# How do I convert, in matlab, numbers in a vector from %c to %.2f so that I may write them to an excel file

Tags: matlab

I am pulling data from a spectrum analyzer into matlab in `%c` format. ex: '-1.223523E+02' char.  I am then putting this into a vector and trying to push to excel but failing.  Is there a way to change this to a number format or way to push into excel?  I will ideally be pushing a vector with 20 numbers in it iterated many times.
Example:

```
i=0;
b=0;
while i<=100;
    d1='-5.678E+02';
    d2='-6.323E+02';
    d3='-5.924E+02';
    b=i+1
    a=[d1, d2, d3];
    c=sprint('b%d:d%d',b,b);
    x1range=c;
    xlswrite(filename,a,x1range);
    i=i+1;
end
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looking for [`str2num`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) or `str2double` to convert your strings into numeric variables.

for example:

```
vec=str2num({d1, d2, d3});
```

or:

```
vec=[str2double(d1), str2double(d2), str2double(d3)];
```

Comment: @tjshaffe please see my edit. have you read the linked documentation on str2num? have you looked in a debugger on the value of a?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried that earlier.   I'm pulling out 13 char strings, is there a way to export multiples of those at the same time into excel without changing to a number format?

Comment: a is 1x39char, when using str2num or str2double it is [ ].

Comment: @tjshaffe read the documentation of str2num it seems like the solution you are seeking

Comment: @tjshaffe you might need to break a into a cell array. look I to regexp as well

Comment: vec=str2double({d1, d2, d3});  worked but doing them individually failed.   Thank you very much for the help, you're a lifesaver.